# Javascript Loops with HTML/JQuery visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to make a loop that checks a few things before continuing. I am open to new idea's if a loop would not be the best way of making this happen.

**Please Note: I apologize if this is worded really badly, it was rushed.**

**UPDATE:**

Lets rephrase this with actual examples. 
I am doing this through snippets (Chrome) so this is not built into the website nor do I own the website, I am just creating a tool to make this a lot easier for me.

Instead of rows lets call them "Tasks". When I open a Task, `$('#workRequestDetailsPanel')` becomes visible. Once this is visible I want to submit the Task by running a command that looks like this `app.workRequestDetails.SubmitWorkRequestDetails()`. When this function is ran, it closes the task allowing the opening of a new task. If I open a new task while one is already open, it crashes and requires me to reload the website so I need to wait for the entire process to end before opening a new task.

This example kinda works, but is using timing the the website is really bad at. For example, sometimes it takes longer than 4 seconds to close a task.

```
var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
      if ($('#workRequestDetailsPanel').is(':visible')) {
         app.workRequestDetails.SubmitWorkRequestDetails();
         app.modalPopup.ClosePopup();
         setTimeout(function(){
            if($('#workRequestDetailsPanel').length == 0){
                  app.dashboardGridview.OpenPopup($('.GVSingleCheckbox').eq(1).attr('id'));
            }else{
                  app.workRequestDetails.CloseWorkrequestDetailsPopup();
            }
         }, 4000);
      }
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Too many factors to know the best solution. The only thing that should take any time would be image loading and ajax requests. Think Asynchronous! Consider a Promise structure.

Comment: @StackSlave Sorry, I believe I corrected it to better represent what I am trying to do.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: The visibility doesn't really change, or at least the attribute doesn't. The ```visibility``` stays set to true, it just moves it back I believe. Mutation Observer has never been something I played with so I don't know much about it/whether or not I am using it correctly.

Comment: Your edit removed the code you were using and therefore made the question off-topic. Consider adding it back.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for the tip, didn't know it did that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, comes to mind:

```js
// Check our limit, so that we don't end up with an infinite loop. 
// You should replace this with the length of the available table rows
let numOfRows = 10; 

// Start from the first row
let currentRow = 1;

// Rows are laballed like this: #row_1, #row_2, ... #row_n
function checkRow( rowNum ){

    let checkExist = setInterval(function() {
        if ( $('#row_' + rowNum ).is(':visible') ) { //once visible, close the "row"
           close( rowNum ); // Close current row
           currentRow++; // Increment the currentRow
           clearInterval( checkExist );
           // If we have more rows to check, run the function again using the incremented number
           if ( currentRow <= numOfRows ){
               checkRow( currentRow );
           }
        }
      }, 100); // every tick check if the element is visible (this signifies if the "row" is open)

}

checkRow( currentRow ); // Start checking row #1. Recursion will take care of the rest.
```

I am not sure, exactly what the `close()` function does and how exactly the rows become visible, but this code might be a good starting point for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Updated the question, it was poorly worded and I feel like I fixed most of the mistakes made in it.